# How to safely convert a string and extract an integer from it and return the set

Tags: scala

I have a set of strings that look like:

```
"user-123"
"user-498"
"user-9891"
```

I want to return a set of integers like this:

```
123
498
9891
```

I can do this:

```
val mySet = // ....

mySet.map(x => x.replace("user-").toInt)
```

But if the toInt parsing fails it will crash, what would be a safer way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To ignore failed strings:

```
mySet.flatMap(s => Try(s.replace("user-", "").toInt).toOption)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check for strings that will successfully convert to an `Int`:

```
mySet.map(_.stripPrefix("user-")).collect { case x if x.forall(_.isDigit) => x.toInt }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `isDigit()`

`Try("user-1234".toCharArray.filter(_.isDigit)
   .foldLeft("")((a, b) => a + b).toInt)
   .getOrElse(0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple regular expression to only keep the numerical values.

Something like this:

```
val mySet = Seq("user-123","user-498","user-9891")
mySet.map(_.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""))
```